# Imgur API GET request always returns 404 page in Android but works in POSTMAN

Tags: android, http, okhttp, imgur, unirest

This is driving me insane. I am trying to do a very simple GET request to the Imgur API to get the images from an album as per their API https://apidocs.imgur.com/#3606f862-8281-48f1-b0f7-49a5f77da0e1

It works perfectly well in Postman, but whatever method I try to do a GET request in Android I always get a 404 page. An actual HTML page at that, not an API formatted JSON response. Here is the code I have been running inside an AsyncTask.

This is the version with OkHttp:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = null;
        try {

            request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(new URL("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/6BUjs/images?v=4"))
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36")
                    .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("OKHttpError", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("OKHttpError", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

This is the version with Unirest

```
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0);
        Unirest.clearDefaultHeaders();
        try {
            response = Unirest.get("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/6BUjs/images?v=14")
                    .header("Authorization", ("Client-ID " + clientId))
                    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Accept","application/json")
                    .asString();

        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            Log.e("HTTP Exception", e.getMessage());
        }
        return response.getBody();
```

And this is the version with HttpURLConnection

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/6BUjs/images");
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("GET");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
            http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            http.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36");

            return http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

Here is the full class file for reference:

```
public class ImgurAlbumAPIClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String clientId = "5070e3bc69f6159";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = null;
        try {

            request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(new URL("https://api.imgur.com/3/album/6BUjs/images?v=4"))
                    .method("GET", null)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36")
                    .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("OKHttpError", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("OKHttpError", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String body) {
        Log.d("ImgurAPI", body);
    }
}
```

It really is a very simple class with a very simple goal. I have been rocking my brain. Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: SOLVED!!! Imgur has changed its API policy and only public albums can now be listed without OAuth authorization. The album I was trying to access, which did previously get surfaced by the API is hidden/unlisted. The reason why posting with a plugin from my browser returned the proper result was that my Cookie was being sent as well. Imgur should still NOT return an actual HTML 404 page from their JSON API in this particular case instead of a useful error message!!!
TL;DR You need a public Imgur album.